# PyQt: connecting slots with custom objects via Qt Designer

Tags: qt, numpy, pyqt

I have a PyQt widget that sends signals with `numpy.ndarray` data. And I have another PyQt widget that has a slot with `numpy.ndarray` data.

Both widget are located on my main window, that is compiled from *.ui file. The widgets are set as promoted widgets.

Cannot I somehow connect the signal and slot in Qt Creator?

Just now it gives me the next error:

```
TypeError: C++ type 'ndarray' is not supported as a slot argument type
```

Answer (score 1):

Reason for this is Qt only support the datatype defined in QMetaType passed as argument of signal, looks here http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qmetatype.html#Q_DECLARE_METATYPE
According to ekhumoro's POST, I update the following code, it should work for PyQt4, not tested on PyQt5.

```
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from numpy import *


class MyThread(QThread):
    mysignal = pyqtSignal(ndarray)

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MyThread, self).__init__(parent)

    def run(self):
        while True:
            QThread.msleep(100)
            self.mysignal.emit(array((1, 2, 3, 4)))


class MyWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MyWidget, self).__init__(parent)
        self.thread = MyThread()
        self.thread.mysignal.connect(self.handleSignal)
        self.thread.start()

    def handleSignal(self, data):
        print data


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MyWidget()
    w.show()
    app.exec_()
```

Comment: The `setattr` line does nothing and is not needed. There is no way way to register new metatypes in pyqt (nor is there any need to). In your example code, it isn't even necessary to declare the signal argument type as `ndarray` - using `object` will work just as well.

Comment: @ ekhumoro, you are right, no need to use setattr .