# How to handle data in a tree by QAbstractModel?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

There some examples which explaines how model functions work. Thats fine! But they have all one handicap. The usage of data, thats nowhere described. The doc says:

> In a real application, MyModel would have a member called MyData,
>   which serves as the target for all reading and writing operations.

As a newbie I was searching for some 'MyModel' examples, of course. I found some which most handles some simple data mechanism based on lists like [here](http://trevorius.com/scrapbook/uncategorized/pyqt-custom-abstractitemmodel/) or a very sophisticated [setupModelData](https://github.com/baoboa/pyqt5/blob/master/examples/itemviews/simpletreemodel/simpletreemodel.py) which is based on a formated file. More close to a practical situation are e.g. Yasin Uludag's Tutorial (see yasinuludag.com/blog/?p=98) which uses an own **itemModel**.

But how to deal with other data structures? 
I have an simple object which contains a Dictionary where I store datapointer to databasetables and other things

```
class ObjDict(dict):
    def __getattr__(self,attr):
        return self[attr]
    def __setattr__(self,attr,value):
        self[attr]=value
```

I use it in a class StructureItem as dataSet where dataSet.name will be `Qt.DisplayRole` and dataSet will be `Qt.UserRole`. This works.

```
class StructureItem(object):
    def __init__(self, name, dataSet, parent=None):
        if SRCDEBUG : print("StructureItem.__init__")
        self._name = dataSet.name
        self._dataSet = dataSet
        self._children = []
        self._parent = parent
        self._structureList = []
        if parent is not None:
            parent.addChild(self)
...
```

This will be used in the model as self._rootNode

```
class StructureModel(QAbstractItemModel):
    """INPUTS: Node, QObject"""
    dragDropFinished = pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self, root, parent=None):
        super(StructureModel, self).__init__(parent)
        self._rootNode = root
    ...
```

It works fine until it comes to drag & drop. I get an error in `dropMimeData` because the insert requests an type of *StructureItem* but I have only the *text* type from `mimeData.setData`.

My questions: Is there a general fault in my model thinking (usage of a dictionary as `data`) or how to handle data structures based on dictionaries e.g. ?
What does Qt mean with the MyData member? Isn't it the *StructureItem Object* ?

Comment: Regarding d&d I get a little bit further. [link]http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmimedata.html#setData  say: Note that if you want to use a custom data type in an item view drag and drop operation, you must register it as a Qt meta type, using the Q_DECLARE_METATYPE() macro, and implement stream operators for it. The stream operators must then be registered with the qRegisterMetaTypeStreamOperators() function. Fine, can someone give me a python example, please?

Comment: I found a confusing answer from ekhumoro
link[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28700989/pyqt-connecting-slots-with-custom-objects-via-qt-designer]: _There is no way way to register new metatypes in pyqt (nor is there any need to)_

Comment: There is nothing in the least bit confusing about my comment if you read all of it. Here's the vital part you missed out: "it isn't even necessary to declare the signal argument type as `ndarray` - using `object` will work just as well". The answer I commented on shows exactly how to solve the problem without any need for registering meta-types.

Comment: Sorry, it's confusing to mee. To be honest, I am not a professional software engineer and it's a hard way to figure out how I may use this to solve for my d&d problem. Especially, because I don't know if its a design or code problem. But I try to understand your answers, you can be sure.

Comment: My comment was on an answer to a question about signals. Your question doesn't seem to have anything to do with signals. Perhaps that is the source of your confusion. In one of your previous questions, I advised you not to use a custom model, because it is an advanced approach that is difficult to get right. A `QStandardItemModel` is a much better choice - especially if you're fairly new to model/view programming in qt.

Comment: You're right and I did use a QStandartmodel first, but was runing into problems with my data design. I found Uludag's tutorials which I did understand very well. But he uses QAbstractModel. So I changed my design. No, I am on the way back and don't know exactly why I am failing. It couldn't be that hard, but as I wrote I have too little basics and there is no documentation availible which is about pyqt5. I did read all related chapters in the books about pyqt4 (not that much). What was your way to become an expert?

Comment: I certainly wouldn't call myself an expert. I have been using pyqt for many years, so it is just a steady accumulation of knowledge. I learned almost everything from the Qt docs (but I have very little C++ knowledge). The rest comes from trial and error, plus searching for code examples on the web (most of which come from SO).